# Rails eager loading seems to be querying wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, query-optimization, eager-loading

I'm attempting to eager load in my Rails 3 app.  I've narrowed it down to a very basic sample, and instead of generating the one query I'm expecting, it's generating 4.

First, here's a simple breakdown of my models.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gender

  def to_param
    self.name
  end
end

class Gender < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles, :dependent => :nullify
end
```

I then has a ProfilesController::show action, where's I'm querying for the model.

```
def ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_profile, :only => [:show]

  def show
  end

  private

    def find_profile
      @profile = Profile.find_by_username(params[:id], :include => :gender)
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, "Page not found" unless @profile
    end
end
```

When I look at the queries this generates, it shows the following:

```
SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`username` = 'matt' LIMIT 1
SELECT `genders`.* FROM `genders` WHERE (`genders`.`id` = 1)
```

What I expected to see is a single query:

```
SELECT `profiles`.*, `genders`.* FROM `profiles` LEFT JOIN `genders` ON `profiles`.gender_id = `genders`.id WHERE `profiles`.`username` = 'matt' LIMIT 1
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?  Everything I've found on eager loading makes it sound like this should work.

**Edit:** After trying `joins`, as recommended by sled, I'm still seeing the same results.

The code:

```
@profile = Profile.joins(:gender).where(:username => params[:id]).limit(1).first
```

The query:

```
SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` INNER JOIN `genders` ON `genders`.`id` = `profiles`.`gender_id` WHERE `profiles`.`username` = 'matt' LIMIT 1
```

Again, you can see no `genders` data is being retrieved, and so a second query to `genders` is being made.

I even tried adding a `select`, to no avail:

```
@profile = Profile.joins(:gender).select('profiles.*, genders.*').where(:username => params[:id]).limit(1).first
```

which correctly resulted in:

```
SELECT profiles.*, genders.* FROM `profiles` INNER JOIN `genders` ON `genders`.`id` = `profiles`.`gender_id` WHERE `profiles`.`username` = 'matt' LIMIT 1
```

...but it still performed a second query on `genders` later when accessing `@profile.gender`'s attributes.

**Edit 2:** I also tried creating a scope that includes both `select` and `joins` in order to get all the fields I require, (similar to the custom left join method sled demonstrated).  It looks like this:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  ALL_ATTRIBUTES = [:photo, :city, :gender, :relationship_status, :physique, :children,
    :diet, :drink, :smoke, :drug, :education, :income, :job, :politic, :religion, :zodiac]

  scope :with_attributes,
    select((ALL_ATTRIBUTES.collect { |a| "`#{reflect_on_association(a).table_name}`.*" } + ["`#{table_name}`.*"]).join(', ')).
    joins(ALL_ATTRIBUTES.collect { |a|
      assoc = reflect_on_association(a)
      "LEFT JOIN `#{assoc.table_name}` ON `#{table_name}`.#{assoc.primary_key_name} = `#{assoc.table_name}`.#{assoc.active_record_primary_key}"
    }.join(' '))
  # ...
end
```

This generates the following query, which appears correct:

```
SELECT `photos`.*, `cities`.*, `profile_genders`.*, `profile_relationship_statuses`.*, `profile_physiques`.*, `profile_children`.*, `profile_diets`.*, `profile_drinks`.*, `profile_smokes`.*, `profile_drugs`.*, `profile_educations`.*, `profile_incomes`.*, `profile_jobs`.*, `profile_politics`.*, `profile_religions`.*, `profile_zodiacs`.*, `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` LEFT JOIN `photos` ON `profiles`.photo_id = `photos`.id LEFT JOIN `cities` ON `profiles`.city_id = `cities`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_genders` ON `profiles`.gender_id = `profile_genders`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_relationship_statuses` ON `profiles`.relationship_status_id = `profile_relationship_statuses`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_physiques` ON `profiles`.physique_id = `profile_physiques`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_children` ON `profiles`.children_id = `profile_children`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_diets` ON `profiles`.diet_id = `profile_diets`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_drinks` ON `profiles`.drink_id = `profile_drinks`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_smokes` ON `profiles`.smoke_id = `profile_smokes`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_drugs` ON `profiles`.drug_id = `profile_drugs`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_educations` ON `profiles`.education_id = `profile_educations`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_incomes` ON `profiles`.income_id = `profile_incomes`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_jobs` ON `profiles`.job_id = `profile_jobs`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_politics` ON `profiles`.politic_id = `profile_politics`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_religions` ON `profiles`.religion_id = `profile_religions`.id LEFT JOIN `profile_zodiacs` ON `profiles`.zodiac_id = `profile_zodiacs`.id WHERE `profiles`.`username` = 'matt' LIMIT 1
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that calls to relationship attributes (e.g.: `@profile.gender.name`) are using the data that was returned in the original SELECT.  Instead, I see a flood of queries following this first one:

```
Profile::Gender Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `profile_genders`.* FROM `profile_genders` WHERE `profile_genders`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Profile::Gender Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `profile_genders`.* FROM `profile_genders` INNER JOIN `profile_attractions` ON `profile_genders`.id = `profile_attractions`.gender_id WHERE ((`profile_attractions`.profile_id = 2))
City Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `cities`.* FROM `cities` WHERE `cities`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Country Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `countries`.* FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`id` = 228 ORDER BY FIELD(code, 'US') DESC, name ASC LIMIT 1
Profile Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
Profile::Language Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `profile_languages`.* FROM `profile_languages` INNER JOIN `profile_profiles_languages` ON `profile_languages`.id = `profile_profiles_languages`.language_id WHERE ((`profile_profiles_languages`.profile_id = 2))
SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `profile_ethnicities` INNER JOIN `profile_profiles_ethnicities` ON `profile_ethnicities`.id = `profile_profiles_ethnicities`.ethnicity_id WHERE ((`profile_profiles_ethnicities`.profile_id = 2))
Profile::Religion Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `profile_religions`.* FROM `profile_religions` WHERE `profile_religions`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
Profile::Politic Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `profile_politics`.* FROM `profile_politics` WHERE `profile_politics`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your example is fine and it will end up in two queries because that's how eager loading is implemented in rails. It becomes handy if you have many associated records. You can read more about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

What you probably want is a simple join:

```
@profile = Profile.joins(:gender).where(:username => params[:id])
```

**Edit**

If the profile consists of many pieces there are multiple approaches here:

Custom left joins - maybe there is a plugin out there which does the job otherwise I'd suggest to do something like:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  # .... code .....

  def self.with_dependencies

    attr_joins    = []
    attr_selects  = []

    attr_selects << "`profiles`.*"
    attr_selects << "`genders`.*"
    attr_selects << "`colors`.*"

    attr_joins << "LEFT JOIN `genders` ON `gender`.`id` = `profiles`.gender_id"
    attr_joins << "LEFT JOIN `colors` ON `colors`.`id` = `profiles`.color_id"

    prep_model  = select(attr_selects.join(','))

    attr_joins.each do |c_join|
      prep_model = prep_model.joins(c_join)
    end

    return prep_model
  end

end
```

Now you could do something like:

```
@profile = Profile.with_dependencies.where(:username => params[:id])
```

Another solution is to use the `:include => [:gender, :color]` it may be some queries more but it's the cleaner "rails way". If you run into performance issues you may want to rethink your DB Schema but do you have really such a heavy load?

**A friend of mine wrote a nice little solution for this simple 1:n relations (like genders) it's called [simple_enum](https://github.com/lwe/simple_enum)**

Comment: However, I believe Rails will join these into a single query if the search conditions require it (for example, `@profile = Profile.includes(:gender).where("genders.name = '...'")`)

Comment: You're right but it's not recommended _Even though Active Record lets you specify conditions on the eager loaded associations just like joins, the recommended way is to use joins instead._ [source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)

Comment: Ultimately, I have multiple relationships I will be joining to the `profile`, and sometimes these associations will be null.  As such, I'm going to need to do a left join.  Does that mean that I have to fully write out a left join along with the table name for each join, or is there a better way in Rails 3?

Comment: Thanks sled.  Unfortunately, it looks like multiple queries are still being created.  I updated my question with the code & associated queries being generated.

Comment: uhm yes, that's an important point - if you join something rails won't populate it as "association" object. Rails just mixes the gender attributes with the attributes of the profile. So the usage of joins in rails is more or less to reduce the result set and not for retrieving "information" ;) So the easiest solution is to stick with the `:include => [...]` solution and forget about the multiple queries. Maybe you want to use a plugin like the [simple_enum](https://github.com/lwe/simple_enum) I've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I've included my solution as an answer, but marking yours as correct since it's what got me to the solution I now have.

Answer (score 1):

After working with sled's suggestions, I finally came up with this solution.  I'm sure it could be made cleaner with a plugin, but here's what I've got for now:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  ALL_ATTRIBUTES = [:photo, :city, :gender, :relationship_status, :physique, :children,
    :diet, :drink, :smoke, :drug, :education, :income, :job, :politic, :religion, :zodiac]

  scope :with_attributes,
    includes(ALL_ATTRIBUTES).
    select((ALL_ATTRIBUTES.collect { |a| "`#{reflect_on_association(a).table_name}`.*" } + ["`#{table_name}`.*"]).join(', '))
end
```

The two main points are:

- A call to `includes`, which passes the symbols of the relationships I want
- A call to `select` that makes sure to retrieve all columns for the related tables.  Note that I call `reflect_on_association` so that I don't have to hard-code the related tables' names, letting the Rails models do the work for me.

I can now call:

```
Profile.with_attributes.where(:username => params[:id]).limit(1).first
```

Going to mark sled's answer as correct since it's his help (answers + comments combined) that led me here, even though this is the code I'm ultimately using.